# Rails rspec undefined method for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller

I have set_seo method in my ApplicationController

```
def set_seo(page)
   set_meta_tags :site => '', :title => page.seo_title ? page.seo_title : '', :reverse => true,
              :description => page.seo_description ? page.seo_description : ""
end
```

and want to test my BrandsController which includes this method

```
 def index
    #some code here
    set_seo(@content)
 end
```

my controller spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe BrandsController do
  render_views
  before(:all) do
     @content = create(:content)
     create(:user)
  end

  describe "GET index" do
    it "index" do
      allow(ApplicationController).to receive(set_seo(@content)).and_return(set_seco(@content))
      brand = Brand.create
      get :index
      expect(response).to render_template(:index)
    end
```

but i have got

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `set_seo' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::BrandsController::GETIndex:0x007f866daa96c8>
```

Answer (score 0):

`set_seo` isn't defined in your specs, hence the `undefined method` error. You have to pass methods as symbols for mocks/stubs (In other words you're replacing or "mocking" the behavior of the method, not calling it directly).

That said, what's the point of this line: `allow(ApplicationController).to receive(set_seo(@content)).and_return(set_seco(@content))`? Isn't it telling `:set_seo` to return what it already returns?

If you're trying to ensure that `set_seo` is actually called, use the following:

```
expect_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:set_seo).with(@content).and_call_original
```